# Unexpected result in C program with increment operator

Tags: c, operators, increment, post-increment

This statement `int b = (a) + a++;` is supposed to assign the value 8 to variable `b`, where `a` is initially assigned the value 4. However, the output of the program is 9 instead of the expected 8.

I expect 8 to be output because `()` and `++` (post) have same precedence and so by their associativity rule `(a)` should be evaluated first and then `a++`, both of which evaluate to 4. Hence we should have `4 + 4`, which equals '8'.

I would like to understand the reasons behind this unexpected result. Why is the output 9 instead of 8? How does the order of evaluation and the behavior of the increment operator contribute to this outcome?

Comment: Precedence does not dictate order of evaluation (see e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67689209/operator-precedence-versus-order-of-evaluation)

Comment: Save/Print [Associativity&Precedence Order Chart](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~i109/Notes/COperatorPrecedenceTable.pdf) and learn from the top down approach, it will make sense

Comment: This question was closed to an inappropriate duplicate.  This is not a duplicate of [**Why are these constructs using pre and post-increment undefined behavior?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior).  That question involves multiple unsequenced assignments to a single variable.  There is only one assignment to `a` in this question.  I've reopened the question so that it either gets a proper answer or, worst case, gets closed to an actual duplicate.

Comment: `int b = (a) + a++;` is absolutely equivalent to `int b = a + a++;` or `int b = (a) + ((((a++))));` or `int b = ((((a))) + ((((((a++))))))));` or ... and, as said in other comments, **Undefined Behaviour**.

Comment: @AndrewHenle It looks like that question includes cases like `printf("%d %d\n", ++w, w);` that are applicable here, and would be appropriate.

Comment: @pmg I'm pretty certain `int b = (a) + a++;` is not undefined behavior, but it is unspecified behavior.  Undefined behavior would be invoked with multiple unsequenced assignments, but that's not present.

Comment: @dbush Yes, a full reading of the question and its answers does address that, but the title of the question is **Why are these constructs using pre and post-increment undefined behavior?**, IMO making the dupe reason wrong.  For example, even [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51876456/4756299) seems to characterize the behavior of code very similar to `printf("%d %d\n", ++w, w);` as "undefined", when I'm pretty sure it's "unspecified".  That's a subtle but IMO important difference.

Comment: @AndrewHenle UB doesn't necessarily have to be two unsequenced writes, it can be an unsequenced read and write as in this example.  C11s6.5p2: *"If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect
on the same scalar object **or a value computation using the value of the same scalar
object**, the behavior is undefined.*"